# R Summarise (aggregate) a data frame with counts or statistics

Tags: r, categories, summary

I would like to summarise (or aggregate) a data frame so that factors are summarised as counts and numbers are summarised by means.

So for df1, I would like the output summarised by cat1 to be as df2. Thanks.

```
id1 <- 1:10
cat1 <- c("A","A","A","B","C","C","C","C","C","C")
fact1 <- c("M","M","F","M","F","F","M","M","M","M")
set.seed(11)
num1 <- runif(10)

df1 <- data.frame(id1, cat1, fact1, num1)
df1$cat1 <- as.factor(df1$cat1)

cat2 <- c("A","B","C")
fact2.F <- c(1, 0, 2)
fact2.M <- c(2, 1, 4)
num2.mean<- c(0.2627922, 0.01404791, 0.3999875)

df2 <- data.frame(cat2, fact2.F, fact2.M, num2.mean)
```

To re-iterate, the summary/aggregation should be done as counts for each level of a factor and as a mean for numeric data. So for cat1=="A" there are two "M"'s and one "F".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **base R** approach, combining 2 `aggregate`s, one for the `mean` of *num1* and one for the `sum` of *fact1*

```
cbind(aggregate(fact1 ~ cat1, df1, function(x) 
        sapply(unique(df1$fact1), function(y) sum(x %in% y))), 
      aggregate(num1 ~ cat1, df1, mean)[-1])
  cat1 fact1.M fact1.F       num1
1    A       2       1 0.26279216
2    B       1       0 0.01404791
3    C       4       2 0.39998755
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `aggregate()` calculating means and with `table()` getting counts:

```r
cbind(
  aggregate(num1 ~ cat1, df1, FUN = mean),
  fact1 = as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1[c('cat1', 'fact1')]))
)

#   cat1       num1 fact1.F fact1.M
# A    A 0.26279216       1       2
# B    B 0.01404791       0       1
# C    C 0.39998755       2       4
```

---

Alternative `dplyr` approaches:

###### Solution 1

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(fact1 = factor(fact1)) %>% 
  summarise(across(fact1, ~ as_tibble(as.list(table(.x))), .unpack = TRUE),
            num1 = mean(num1),
            .by = cat1)
```

###### Solution 2

```r
df1 %>%
  count(cat1, fact1) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = fact1, names_prefix = "fact1_", values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  left_join(summarise(df1, num1 = mean(num1), .by = cat1), by = "cat1")
```

###### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  cat1  fact1_F fact1_M   num1
  <fct>   <int>   <int>  <dbl>
1 A           1       2 0.263 
2 B           0       1 0.0140
3 C           2       4 0.400
```